# Need python 2.7+ but default on system is 2.6

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I downloaded some tools which use python scripts to work. It seems I need python 2.7+ to be able to run the scripts, the default installed is 2.6 and I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'
```

So, I downloaded and installed python 2.7, however I still get the same error. Looks like both versions are separate, rather than 2.7 just being an update, and 2.6 is still the default.

```
# python --version
Python 2.6.6
# python2.7 --version
Python 2.7.10
```

I can't see any way to run the scripts directly and not sure how else to resolve this. Using RHEL6

Comment: How do you start the scripts?

Comment: 1. Don't mess with the default Python interpreter on your system; 2. Why can't you just run the code with the new interpreter? 3. The problem is probably not with the version.

Comment: Have you tried to either change the command (execute as `python2.7 scriptname.py`) or add a shebang (put `#! /usr/bin/env python2.7` at the top of the script)? Trying to replace the system Python installation will probably end disastrously.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not a good idea to change the default python interpreter unless you know what you are doing. You could try aliasing the python command.

```
alias python="python2.7"
```

To revert just type `unalias python`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your scripts has

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

as hash-bang.

Change the first line of your scripts to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

given that python 2.7 indeed is available on the system.

This way, when you run the scripts from the path, it'll run in python2.7

Answer (score 0):

do this:

> which python 
>   /usr/bin/python
>
> ls -l /usr/bin/python 
>   /usr/bin/python -> python2.7

so you just need to update /usr/bin/python link to point to your python 2.7, just remember if you use centos YUM package manager, it is linked to python, so if you clear your old python, yum will not work.

Answer (score 0):

? CentOS 6 ?

`python27` is available : http://vault.centos.org/6.5/SCL/x86_64/python27/